# bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gcloud

I want to extract a table from Bigquery, using python 2.7 and pycharm. I followed the steps proposed by the official google cloud website (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data), but it keeps giving me the "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ExtractJobConfig'" error.

The code:

```
from gcloud import bigquery

def bigquery_get_rows ():

    #ININCIALIZACAO DO CLIENTE DE FORMA EXPLICITA
    json_key = "path/to/my/json_key_File.json"
    #storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(json_key)
    bq_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(json_key,project='my_project_name')
    print("\nPeguei o Cliente\n")

    # Make an authenticated API request
    #buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    #print(buckets)
    print("\nPRINTEI OS BUCKETS PARA TESTAR SE PEGOU O CLIENTE MERMO\n")
    #print(storage_client)
    print(bq_client)
    print("\n NAO EH QUE EU PEGUEI O TAL DO CLIENTE MERMO")

    #Setando ambiente
    project = 'my_project'
    print(project)
    bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
    print(bucket_name)
    destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'TESTE_Lista_Padrao_Mailchimp_Automatizada.json')
    print(destination_uri)
    dataset_ref = bq_client.dataset('my_dataser_ref')
    print(dataset_ref)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(name='my_table_ref')
    print(table_ref)

    #Configuracao do job
    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    job_config.destination_format = (bigquery.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON)

    #Extraindo tabela
    extract_job = bq_client.extract_table(table_ref, destination_uri, job_config=job_config,location='US')  # API request
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
    print('Exported {}:{}.{} to {}'.format(project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri))

bigquery_get_rows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using the wrong library.

I just changed from

```
from gcloud import bigquery
```

to

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

and it is working now